# What is the purpose of the carriage-return/tab sequence in this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

In a stored-proc. I'm studying, I keep seeing lines like this:

```
IF @IsSupplierUser = 0
    SET @SQL += CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,cs.FEDSurveyName as ''Complete Survey Name'''
```

What is the purpose of putting tabs/carriage-returns when SQL by default will just put out a standard table of cells anyway? Isn't the output already a CSV file by default?

Am I missing something really  obvious?

thanks

Comment: Purpose? For output formatting would be my guess.

Comment: If it's a complicated procedure, and you're dynamically building it, if you need to `PRINT @SQL` to help debug it, the SQL query will be nicely formatted. Other than that, nothing really.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - OK so it's just formating , thanks!

Comment: Formatting the Sql command that will generate the the output... but in this example, it has nothing to do with formatting the output itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the stored procedure is using dynamic SQL, and perhaps the person that originally wrote it was potentially doing this for ease of readability. There might even be a commented out (or not) statement that does `PRINT(@SQL)`.

Other than that from the short snippet there, I see no reason to put the spaces/new line in there.